# Get record by id number mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This  is my database structure.

```
id   userid
1    x
2    xx
3    xxx
4    xx
```

I want to display row no. 3 in php. Only userid by row number.

Result should be :

```
xxx
```

Comment: `SELECT userid FROM yourtable WHERE id=3`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select userid from table where id=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this query

```
SELECT userid FROM table WHERE id=3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "db_username", "db_password", "db_name");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` = '3' LIMIT 1");
    $record = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    echo $record->userid;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

***look here this answer and sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f001f/2***

***mysql:***

```
SELECT id, userid 
FROM t 
WHERE id=3;
```

***php:***

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id,userid FROM t WHERE id = 3");
```